# Show/Hide Password

Tags: password

Is it possible to have a show/hide password function in a disabled input field?

I want the user to be able to see their password so that they don't have to reset the password in their Account Overview page.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but it's dangerous to store passwords in a way that can be decoded on a screen, and your organization should get away from doing that. Here's why. https://www.howtogeek.com/434930/why-are-companies-still-storing-passwords-in-plain-text/

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, technically. But I think this is not a good practice as the password will still be fetched from the databases and stored in the browser, which is dangerous.

But on second thought, some systems will actually encrypt the password when it's stored in the database. The readable text will be encoded as a hash, a set of strings. So, I don't think this can be fetched for your hide/show purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!